# How to dynamically add an iframe src with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am running into an `Error: $interpolate:interr Interpolation Error` with dynamically putting a youtube video into an iframe.

html

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="{{youtubeVideo}}" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Javascript/Angular

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: getTankVideos(query)
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.debug('response');
    console.debug(response);

    $scope.youtube = response;
    console.log('Youtube');
    console.log($scope.youtube);

    console.log('Video Url');
    $scope.youtubeVideo = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + $scope.youtube.data.items[0].id.videoId;
    console.log($scope.youtubeVideo);

}, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

My debug statements are giving me valid values

```
response
script.js:129 Object {data: Object, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: ""}
script.js:131 Youtube
script.js:132 Object {data: Object, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: ""}
script.js:134 Video Url
script.js:135 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRtj_TSOHjw
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For safety,You need to inject the `$sce` service in the controller and trustAsResourceUrl the url there.

```
$scope.youtubeVideo = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + $scope.youtube.data.items[0].id.videoId);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was definitely it